# Time Zone in SQL query using springboot

Tags: sql, reactjs, spring, oracle

Currently I'm trying to display current timezone along with date ,but I'm unable to print the timezone

The tried below:

```
select to-char(col1,'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM table_name WHERE id = :tId;
select to-char(col1,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SSxFF AM TZH:TZM') FROM table_name WHERE id = :tId;
```

these two ways are not working and got the below error
"date format not recognized"
Expected O/P : **colname
05/11/2023 10:23 AM EST**

Currently I'm using Springboot , reactjs and Oracle sql.
Can anyone advice on this ..
Thank you

Comment: please always provide a [mre] with your query  see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and  make a https://dbfiddle.uk/7Jxju0AY

Comment: `to-char` does not exist in Oracle, please provide valid code.

Comment: Have a look at [Datetime Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-49B32A81-0904-433E-B7FE-51606672183A). `MM` stands for Months, not Minute. Use `MI`

Comment: What is the data type of `col1`?

Answer (score 0):

Should be this one:

```
select to_char(col1,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM TZR') 
FROM table_name 
WHERE id = :tId;
```

Maybe instead of `TZR` you need `TZD`. From your example it is not clear what you are looking for, check with

```
SELECT tzabbrev, tzname, TZ_OFFSET(tzname) 
FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES tz 
WHERE tzabbrev = 'EST'
   OR tzname = 'EST';
```